# Why does IE not respect my CSS for UL?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to create a CSS/Javascript dropdown list for my site [here](http://ewsit.dadelamkins.com/).  According to this screenshot site (and from what I've noticed on my own) IE 7, 8, and 9 all display this nav bar incorrectly:

http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/bb5c5862f3c3251a60826363d76acf55b2ae5f40

Is there anything I can do about this?  What are my options here?

Comment: It's IE. It respects microsoft. And I'm not even sure about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, your page is running in IE5 Quirks mode by default in these older versions of IE:

[image]

Take a look at your markup and you'll see your missing something (hint: it's the opening `<html>` tag).

Comment: Does it not respect the `<!DOCTYPE html>` that I've specified at the top of my page?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the opening `<html>` element in your document, just include it right after your doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
```

and it should prevent IE from triggering Quirks Mode

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of IE interpret missing or malformed doctypes as "Quirks mode" pages for whatever reason.  Older IE browsers will interpret `<!DOCTYPE html>` as malformed, since they do not support HTML5.  It might be advised to use `<!--[if lt IE 8]>OLDER DOCTYPE<![endif]-->` at the beginning of your browser.

Actually, as Adrift said, the answer is that you forgot the opening `<html>` tag.  I can't believe I overlooked this.